# How can I make sure my edge extrusion is straight towards the middle?

Tags: edit-mode

I am trying to create an opening in my object. I deleted the faces and extruded the remaining edges to create the desired shape, as you can see in the first picture.
As you can also see, it is also deleting parts on the upper and lower side. I just want to have an ellipse like shape, as can be seen in the second picture.

How can I make sure my edge extrusion is straight towards the middle?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is a mirror, activate the clipping property on it.

Comment: Ah of course! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you decide to delete the faces then extrude, make sure that the *Clipping* option of the *Mirror* modifier is activated, so that the vertices along the mirror axis are sticking to each other.

But in your case maybe don't delete the faces and instead inset (<kbd>i</kbd>) and press <kbd>B</kbd> (like *Boundary*) to make the inset stick to the axis:

[image]